# How can show android tablet as a external storage to PC?

Tags: usb-connection-mode

I want to send files to android tablet with a application from PC. - I can send files directly to tablet (2.3 android OS) PC see it as a external usb drive. - But i can't send files to tablet (4.2 android OS), because PC see it as a portable media player.(MTP) - How can i fix this problem ? - How can show my device as a external drive? my application that sent files written via Delphi.

Comment: This sounds to me like a rather development-oriented question. If I'm correct with that, you might be better off at [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) with it, where the programmers are at home. Here at ASE, we are dealing with problems from the **user's end**.

Comment: Is your device in media player mode? Or is it in USB mass storage mode? If you want to move files across the USB, you will need it to be in USB mass storage mode.